# HorizontalScrollView pass items - not giving the items one by one

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview

I am using a [HorizontalScrollView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html) to make a horizontal swipe for a view(contains day and a month of today) and when the user swipes it gives him the day of tomorrow and so on.
It works but the problem that it passes days and doesn't show them.
and I can't work with [ViewPager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) also instead of [HorizontalScrollView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html).

```
  scv=(HorizontalScrollView) view.findViewById(R.id.scv);
    scv.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            ObjectAnimator animator= ObjectAnimator.ofInt(scv, "scrollX",45);
            animator.setDuration(0);
            animator.start();

            calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, +1);
            Date  formattedDate = calendar.getTime();
            dayNumTextView.setText(new SimpleDateFormat("dd").format(formattedDate)+ "");

            monthTextView.setText(new SimpleDateFormat("MMM").format(formattedDate));
            dayNameTextView.setText(new SimpleDateFormat("EEE").format(formattedDate));
            content.getConfirmedAppointments(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
            getCancelledTimeSlots(formattedDate);
            return false;
        }

    });
```

Comment: what issue you are facing?

Comment: it doesn't display all the days

Comment: post your xml and full code.